# Python Can't Send Emails to Gmail

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, gmail, smtplib

I have a python script to send emails.  I utilize this to send alerts to my email and phone.  But for some reason the emails are not received when sending to a gmail account.  The big difference that I see between my code and other examples is I cannot use the smtp.gmail.com.  Here's my email/text function:

```
import smtplib

sender = 'xxxx@company.com'
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')

def text_func ( subject,text_message ):
    text_receivers = ['##########@vtext.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@company.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
    ]
    text_message = """Subject: %s

    %s
    """ % (subject, text_message)

    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, text_receivers, text_message)
```

The above code works for sending an sms to my phone and my work email but not to gmail.  I checked and made sure the email doesn't show up in a spam folder.  Google seems to be blocking it completely.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

sender = 'xxxx@company.com'
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')

def text_func ( subject,text_message ):
    text_receivers = ['##########@vtext.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@company.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
    ]

    cont = '''\
       <html>
         <head></head>
         <body>
           <p>{0}</p>
         </body>
       </html>
       '''.format(text_message)

    msgTo = ""
    for person in text_receivers:
        msgTo += "{0} ".format(person)

    msg = MIMEText(cont, 'html')

    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = msgTo

    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, text_receivers, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: You should also explain the solution rather than just posting the code

Answer (score 1):

This may not be correct, as I don't have much experience with the texting side of `smtplib`, but it looks like you need to start the TLS connection. I would change your script to the following:

```py
import smtplib

sender = 'xxxx@company.com'
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')
smtpObj.starttls()

def text_func ( subject,text_message ):
    text_receivers = ['##########@vtext.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@company.com',
        'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
    ]
    text_message = """Subject: %s\n\n%s""" % (subject, text_message)

smtpObj.sendmail(sender, text_receivers, text_message)
```

Comment: When I add that line it throws and error.  I'm trying to troubleshoot this now.

    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.

Comment: @Rachel I have had issues with that in the past, just keep trying different things.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem. When I checked my inbox from webmail, I found that the email was rejected by gmail.
[image: Screenshot]
The problem was solved by adding the "From" header to the email.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

sender_email = "test@example.com"
receiver_email = "example@gmail.com"
password = "pass1234"
host = "example.com"
port = 465
message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Email Subject"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email
text = "This is the email Body"
message.attach(MIMEText(text, "plain"))
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host, port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
    )
```

Comment: yup it worked for me 
im using a cpnael hosting and was unable to send emails with my script, but now it work just fine

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change your gmail settings to allow less secure apps into your account. See link below from Nick, an accounts expert at google.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

> Option 2: Change your settings to allow less secure apps into your
>   account. We don't recommend this option because it can make it easier
>   for someone to break into your account. If you want to allow access
>   anyway, follow these steps: Go to the Less secure apps section of your
>   Google Account. Turn on Allow less secure apps. If you don't see this
>   setting, your administrator might have turned off less secure app
>   account access.

Comment: Good thought but this did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

[Allowing less secure apps to access your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

For Sending the Email:

```
import smtplib

gmail_user = 'you@gmail.com'  
gmail_password = 'P@ssword!'

sent_from = gmail_user  
to = ['me@gmail.com', 'bill@gmail.com']  
subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'  
body = 'Hey, what's up?\n\n- You'

email_text = """\  
From: %s  
To: %s  
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:  
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print 'Email sent!'
except:  
    print 'Something went wrong...'
```

Comment: I don't want to send FROM a gmail account, only TO a gmail account.  And I cannot use smtp.gmail.com, it's coming from my companies internal smtp gateway.